# How to send newly created campaign with mailchimp api v2?

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am using mailchimp api v2. I am using the mailchimp recommended full api v2 php wrapper.  I am able to create a campaign, but not sure how to send it. With the send method, It wants the campaign id, but I am letting mailchimp create the campaign id when creating the campaign.

My create campaign code looks like this:

```
$api_key = "my_api_key";
require('Mailchimp.php');

//Create Campaign
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp($api_key);
$result = $Mailchimp->campaigns->create('regular', 
        array('list_id'               => 'my_list_id',
    'subject'                       => 'This is a test subject',
    'from_email'                        => 'test@test.com',
    'from_name'                         => 'From Name'),
    array('html'                    => '<div>test html email</div>',
    'text'                                  => 'This is plain text.')
);

if( $result === false ) {
    // response wasn't even json
    echo 'didnt work';
}
else if( isset($result->status) && $result->status == 'error' ) {
    echo 'Error info: '.$result->status.', '.$result->code.', '.$result->name.', '.$result->error;
} else {
        echo 'worked';
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you try and `print_r($result)` and see what you're actually getting?

Comment: That is what i ended up doing. This seems to be working.

Comment: Please can you give me the library that you've used?

Comment: I used api v2, however I highly suggest not using this anymore as it will no longer be supported.  MailChimp API v3.0 is now live! Prior versions will no longer be supported after 2016, so all API users should begin transitioning to v3.0.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for me.

```
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp($api_key);
$result = $Mailchimp->campaigns->create('regular', 
        array('list_id'               => 'my_list_id',
    'subject'                           => 'This is a test subjects',
    'from_email'                        => 'test@test.com',
    'from_name'                         => 'From_Name'),
    array('html'                    => '<div>test html email</div>',
    'text'                                  => 'This is plain text.')
);


if( $result === false ) {
    // response wasn't even json
    echo 'sorry';
}
else if( isset($result->status) && $result->status == 'error' ) {
    echo 'Error info: '.$result->status.', '.$result->code.', '.$result->name.', '.$result->error;
} else {
echo 'worked';
$mySend = $Mailchimp->campaigns->send($result['id']);
}
```